# Почему отличается тип передаваемого значения из Spring в Angular?

Tags: html, typescript, spring-boot, angular

Есть контроллер, написанный с помощью `Spring Framework` в котором есть метод, выподляющийся на GET запрос:

```java
@GetMapping
public Page<GiftCertificateDto> findAll(@Valid EsmPagination pagination, @Valid GiftCertificateSearchParameter searchParameter) {
    return searchParameter.isNullAllFields()
            ? service.findAll(pagination).map(linkBuilder::build)
            : service.findAll(pagination, searchParameter).map(linkBuilder::build);
}
```

Метод возвращает параметризованный объек типа `Page<GiftCertificateDto>`, который используется для пагинации. Окей, идём дальше.

Далее в проекте на Angular я хочу получить список объектов типа `GiftCertificateDto`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public giftCertificates!: GiftCertificate[];

  constructor(private giftCertificateService: GiftCertificateService) {
  }

  public findAllGiftCertificates(): void {
    this.giftCertificateService.findAll().subscribe({
        next: (response) => this.giftCertificates = response,
        error: (err: HttpErrorResponse) => alert(err.message)
      });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.findAllGiftCertificates();
  }
}
```

Почему я указал именно `(response) => this.giftCertificates = response`? Intellij IDEA делает автоподстановку типа возвращаемого значения и указывает его как массив `GiftCertificate[]`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окей, пытаюсь на frontend части получить данный массив, но я вынужден использовать там `pipe` с именем `keyvalue`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let page of giftCertificates | keyvalue">
    Key:{{page.key}} | Value:{{page.value}}
</div>
```

И на выходе получаю вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, на выходе я получаю не массив объекто `GiftCertificate[]`, а объект `Record<string, ???>`.

Я пробовал на морде получать массив без использования `pipe`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let certificate of giftCertificates">
    {{certificate.name}}
</div>
```

Но в этом случае я получал ошибку о том, что директиву `*ngFor` нельзя использовать не для простых массивов, значит приходит на морду не простой массив:

```
ERROR Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

Также читал [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809580/how-to-get-list-from-page-in-spring-data-rest), где предлагается изменить тип возвращаемого значения с `Page` на `List` путём правки кода Spring, но надо обойтись без правки кода существующего API.

Также не получается явно указать тип, потому что компиляр прямо говорит, что приходит массив `GiftCertificate[]`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кажется, у вас с сервера приходит не массив данных, но объект страницы с данными. Кажется, вам надо в ангуляре поменять тип возвращаемого значения findAll метода на страницу с результатами, вместо самих результатов.

Comment: У вас есть поле giftCertificates, которому вы задали тип GiftCertificate[], соответственно IDE основываясь на правилах выведения типов, считает, что метод findAll вернет вам GiftCertificate[]. И скорее всего такой жи тип указан в методе findAll. Как заметили выше, надо заменить тип GiftCertificate[] на тип, который соответствует по структуре Page<GiftCertificateDto>